# Add waveform in soundmanager2 like soundcloud

Tags: jquery, soundcloud, waveform, soundmanager2

I am creating a customized music player using `soundmanager2` like **[here](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/)**.

I want to add `waveform` to my music players as like [soundcloud.com](http://soundcloud.com) does already I tried using:

1. http://wavesurfer-js.org/
2. http://waveformjs.org/

But unfortunately I can't :(

Soundcloud is creating image for all the music files but i want it on the fly.

Comment: "but unforchantly i cant"  Why? have you made any attempt at this your self, do you have any code to show us?

Comment: ya simplay i want to mearge soundmanager2 pageplayer.js and waveform.js but its wants image of waveform

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SoundCloud api then each song has a `waveform_url` property which is a link to the image of the waveform.

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks